# Constraint Animation only partially animating causing what looks like a "jump"

Tags: ios, animation, constraints, core-animation

When using the system default animations everything works as expected.  However, when changing a top position constraint inside of  animateWithDuration, the view's height adjustment doesn't animate, it jumps.  And then its position animates to the correct location.

Here is an example video showing the issue: http://www.screencast.com/t/GAEQiGIqS.

The bottom view is blue and you will see that when it needs to shrink it gets "detached" from the bottom of the containing view and then is animated until it contacts the bottom.  I want the bottom view to stay locked to the bottom of the containing view.  Any suggestions?

The vertical constraints are being setup as:

```
constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[topView][bottomView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: metricsDict, views: viewDict)

_bottomViewTopConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: bottomView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: bottomViewMiddlePos)
```

The snap to closest target drop point is done by changing the _bottomViewTopConstraint constant and then invoking the animation:

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
UIView.animateWithDuration((2.3).seconds) {
_bottomViewTopConstraint.constant = currentPosition + shortestDelta
   self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

There are NO errors reporting that constraints had to be broken.  So the AutoLayout system is fine, but it doesn't correctly animate the height change caused by the position change.

Comment: What is the issue, animation not happening during resizing or bottom view is not anchored to the bottom of containing view or both?

Comment: bottom view isn't anchored to the bottom of the containing view.  From this constraint "V:|[topView][bottomView]|".  I also tried "V:|[topView][bottomView]-0@1000-|" with the same results.

Comment: What is container view, a parent class of bottom view?

Comment: Yea the container view is the ViewController's self.view.  topView and bottomView are subviews of that view.

Comment: What do you use this for _bottomViewTopConstraint.constant = currentPosition + shortestDelta?

Comment: It's just computing the new constant value for the _bottomViewTopConstraint.   I let the user drag the view to where they want it, but then it snaps to the nearest "snap" point when they release it.  The shortestDelta represents the distance to the shortest snap point.   That seems to work fine as the bottom view goes to the correct spot.  It's the bottom view 's height and it not staying locked to the bottom that's the problem.

Comment: I am wondering once the bottom view is successfully snapped to the bottom of container view, don't you need to enforce "V:|[topView][bottomView]|" again as the former constraint might have invalidated it earlier?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118640/discussion-between-tod-cunningham-and-ldindu).

Comment: This was happening to me today - the issue was that i was using layoutIfNeeded on the ui element itself but not on the view that holds the element - like you are doing.

Comment: Was this issue ever resolved @TodCunningham? I am correctly calling `layoutIfNeeded` on the superView but still seeing this "jump" that you describe. Would love to know what the solution was for you.

Comment: nvm managed to solve it finally! Since the view I was animating was actually part of a childViewController, calling `layoutIfNeeded` on `view.super` did the trick.